# Prove, if $L$ real symmetric matrix over $S$, then $M(L)$ representing $L$ with base change over an orthonormal base of $S$ is also symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, orthonormal, change-of-basis

im new here, and im having trouble checking some old theorems i didnt prove in their time. This is my first post, and also English is not my native language, so please be patient with me, i will update my question and fix any mistake or add any other requirements y may be missing. I currently only need to prove this, which as been a bit confusing:

Given $L$ a linear transform over $S$ subspace of $R^n$, and $B$ orthonormal base of $S$.
Prove the matrix $M(L)$ representing the transform $L$ after a base change over $B$ (from and into) is also symmetric iff $L$ symmetric.

In other words:

$L$ symmetric <=> $M(L)$ symmetric

PD: i can't directly use $B^⊤$ = $B^{-1}$ if $B$ the orthonormal matrix generated by the base $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $B$ is the orthonormal matrix given by sending the standard basis to your orthonormal basis, then $B$ satisfies $B^{\top} = B^{-1}$, and in particular, if $M_B(L)$ denotes the transformed $L$ with matrix $B$, then
$$
M_B(L)^{\top} = (BLB^{-1})^{\top} = (BLB^{\top})^{\top} = (B^{\top})^{\top} L^{\top} B^{\top} = BLB^{\top} = M_B(L).
$$
Since $L = M_{B^{-1}}(M_B(L))$, you can repeat the argument by substituting $(B,L)$ by $(B^{-1}, M_B(L))$ to prove the equivalence.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks!; that's a nice way, but i want to get the proof without using $B^T$ = $B^-1$ (1), in the notes i'm using they demonstrate (1) a bit after, so i'm really sure it can be done by other means, maybe something related to the spectrum of $L$ being reals and its eigen vectors orthogonals by its symmetry. Or maybe not, but i'm not sure. I feel there should be a shortcut similar to this.
Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasNZ : You can have weird things happen if you don't assume $B$ orthogonal but only invertible. For example, suppose $L$ is just an orthogonal projection onto some proper subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ (which is symmetric). Then $M(L)^{\top} = M(L)$ is equivalent to $(B^{\top}B)^{-1}L(B^{\top}B) = L$. If $B$ is orthogonal, this is always true because $L$ is conjugated by the identity matrix on the LHS. But when not, $B^{\top}B$ could be acting as an automorphism on $L$'s kernel and it wouldn't change the LHS, so the equality would still hold. You can consider $n=3$ and $L$ of rank $1$.

Comment: In that case, $B$ and $B^{\top}$ can do whatever you want on $\ker L$ while fixing $\mathrm{im} L$ and the equality would still hold.

Comment: Im working now so give me a time to think about it, in the meantime, i think its true, weird things happen, but we can still find a way to demonstrate the property without using it, or we cant?, that would interesting to check. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @NicolasNZ : For a linear map $L$ and an invertible matrix $B$, there's no reason why $(B^{\top} B)^{-1} L (B^{\top}B) = L$ should hold. For example, if $A$ is positive-definite and symmetric, then $A = B^{\top} B$ for some upper-triangular matrix $B$ (this is the Cholesky decomposition reformulated).

Comment: So let us consider the example where $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ diagonal matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, and $L$ permutes the two basis vectors. Then $A^{-1}LA$ permutes the two basis vectors and then multiplies the first one by $\lambda_1 \lambda_2^{-1}$ and the second one by $\lambda_2 \lambda_1^{-1}$. This is not what $L$ does, so $A^{-1}LA \neq L$, and if $B^{\top}B = A$, then $M_B(L)$ is not symmetric but $L$ is.